# pytest.yield_fixture using cmd line options

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

is it possible to use pytest_addoption(parser) to create a list that is used by pytest.yield_fixture?  i.e.

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
  parser.addoption("-foo", action="store",defaults="1,2,3")

@pytest.yield_fixture(params=request.config.getoption('--foo').split(','))
def test_bar(request):
  do_something(request.param)
```

say you had 6 browsers, and you wanted to ability to run the tests against 1 browser as a quick check.  I can't figure out how to get in place before test discovery/generation.  Help

Answer (score 0):

This obviously doesn't work since you the `request` variable does not exist in the global module scope, which is when the expression in the decorator is executed.  The way to solve this is use the [pytest_generate_tests](http://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html?highlight=pytest_generate_tests#pytest-generate-tests) hook:

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--foo', action='store', defaults='1,2,3')

def pytest_configure(config):
    config.foo = config.getoption('foo').split(',')

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'foo' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize('foo', metafunc.config.foo)

# test_bar.py
def test_bar(foo):
    do_something(foo)
```